# Moodle error while updating user profile

Tags: moodle

I just created a new user field in my form named UID and marked it required.
Now if I click anywhere on site administration it redirects me to
`edit.php?id=2&course=1` and asks me to update UID and when I try to do it, it says:

> Forbidden
>   You don't have permission to access /user/edit.php on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an `ErrorDocument` to handle the request.